# Hour on MySQL and Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, date

I'm training some CRUD on Java WEB with Spring.

On my CRUD I have four fields: name, value, date, hour.

The problem is, when I add in my database (MySQL) only the name, value and date, through my jsp file it works fine.

But when I try to add the hour i got 404 error, probably because i'm doing something wrong on the convertion.

My hour on Java is Date type, and on MySQL the hour field is datetime.

On my form I want to add the value in HH:mm:ss format.

I'm adding here my two classes on pastebin to keep it clean:

Test.class (java bean):
http://pastebin.com/RtcdzuWV

TestDao.class (dao class):
http://pastebin.com/GYAP4QCX

Can someone help-me on this convertion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Database table create a column that is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

The `TIMESTAMP` SQL type stores both the time and date part of a date. In your java code you will then use `java.sql.Timestamp` in the following manner:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(utilDate);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, teste.getHours());
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, teste.getMinutes());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, teste.getSeconds());
    stmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: But on my Test.class I don't have the methods getMinutes and getSeconds, so, how can I get this values?

Comment: Please use a StringTokenizer to tokenize the string you get from the field for hour or the best way I can think of is to divide your field into 3 dropdown fields and fill them with Hour, Minute and Seconds values then create the fields on your Test object and assign the values from the frontend to them.